# How assign a variable with items from the middle of a list in py

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

From this list I want to retrieve the centre elements at positions 4, 5 and 6. So: `[4,5,6]` is the output I want from this list.

I know how to remove elements, that's easy using this method:

```
x = [position1:] + [:position2]
```

But I don't know how to find those items.

Comment: `thing = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` followed by a `thing[4]`?

Comment: `my_list[4:7]`?

Comment: Yep... simple as that. Thankyou, I'll remove because I couldn't find the other answer before, but it's much more extensive and answers this much better.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[slice](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)**:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(l[4:7]) # [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Yep... simple as that. Thankyou, I'll remove because I couldn't find the other answer before, but it's much more extensive and answers this much better.